# {NativeScript} xcrun: error: unable to find utility "PackageApplication", not a developer tool or in PATH -- Unable to run app on device

Tags: nativescript

I am using NativeScript and recently my XCode got updated to 8.3 and now I am not able to run the application on my device. It is giving me this error.

```
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "PackageApplication", not a developer tool or in PATH
```

I did some search and found this has affected Iconic and Codorva apps too.

Comment: This issue has been already reported here: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/2668  You could review the comment here and try some of the given suggestions - https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/2668#issuecomment-290693371 .

Comment: Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an error caused by an update of XCode. You can update your global version of NativeScript to fix now.

```
npm install -g nativescript
```